# JQuery number only validation

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, validation, testing

```
$('.alphaOnly').bind('keypress', function(event){
     var regex = new RegExp("^[ A-Za-z-.']*$");
     validation(event, regex);
});
```

This is my validation for number only in a input. It works prefectly on desktop, iphone but not in android specifically samsung phone.

Does anyone of you ever encountered this kindof problem?

Comment: `z-.` is not what you expect. Escape the hyphen, `z\-.` `bind()` is deprecated, use `on()`.

Comment: I commented the wrong code

Comment: $('.alphaOnly').on('keypress', function(event){
        var regex = new RegExp("^[ A-Za-z\-.']*$");
        validation(event, regex);

    });

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to achieve this.
1. Use onkeypress event of javascript and allow to enter numeric value only. In this way you will not able to enter decimal values.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

2. Check below snippet. In this way you will be able to enter decimal values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtboxToFilter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this way

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\d');
```

Have no  Samsung, but on my android device works as it should
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldfngex4/).